# Setting Non-Empty Client Token in Laravel 8 Boot Method with Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

I am working with Laravel version 8, and I want to use the **global scope** to add a where clause to all queries of the **User** model.

```
/**
* The "booting" method of the model.
* @return void
*/
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    if (!empty(Client::$Current_Token)) {
        static::addGlobalScope(new ClientTokenScope);
    }
}
```

**Main Problem:** The issue I'm facing is that the variable `Client::$Current_Token` I want to add to this global scope is not set when executing the boot method. This is because this variable is set in a middleware.

How can I resolve the issue so that when executing the boot method, the client token is set and not empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `booted` method instead of the boot method. `booted` method is called after all of the booting is completed and you can ensure that value is being set in middleware for `Client::$Current_Token`.

```
public function booted()
{
    if (!empty(Client::$Current_Token)) {
        static::addGlobalScope(new ClientTokenScope);
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me and i don't know why?